# How to make my code shorter / more efficient

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a "Getting error procedure too large" in a VBA macro in Excel. It is not that large, but it is most likely due to me being new to coding and using a very inefficient way of doing it. I basically move some shapes around Excel given I modify a certain cell with a shape. Kind of created a dynamic Gantt chart. But there are too many figures, figures named "y.x" wherey is 1-10 and x is 1-21. I think I should be able to use for loops to do this but I am not sure how to approach it.

```
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pentagon 1.1"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CL5")) Is Nothing Then
            .Visible = True
            .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)
            .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0)
        Else
    End If
End With
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pentagon 1.2"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CM5")) Is Nothing Then
            .Visible = True
            .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)
            .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0)
        Else
    End If
End With
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pentagon 1.3"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("CN5")) Is Nothing Then
            .Visible = True
            .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)
            .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0)
        Else
    End If
    End With
```

This works perfectly as intended, it is just that after x number of figures, the code gets too big and I get an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Factor out the fixed parts of your code into a separate sub, which takes the variable parts as parameters.  There are clear similarities in the 3 blocks you posted.

Comment: Exactly how is this code being run ? - it looks like an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub MoveSomeShapes()
    DisplayShape "Pentagon 1.1", Range("CL5")
    DisplayShape "Pentagon 1.2", Range("CM5")
    DisplayShape "Pentagon 1.3", Range("CN5")
End Sub

Sub DisplayShape(ShapeName As String, TargetCell As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ShapeName))
        If Not Intersect(Target, TargetCell) Is Nothing Then
            .Visible = True
            .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)
            .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The naming of the methods is not good, but since I don't know what they are doing, I had to improvise. I haven't tested it either, but I hope it conveys the idea

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might make sense. I will try it out later today and see if it works, will update as soon as I do!

Comment: It gives me a compile error: only comments may appear after end sub end function or end property. I will try figuring out

Comment: Each line starting with `Function` must have a corresponding `End Function`. Same goes for `Sub` and `End Sub`. The can only be code between these. There can't be any Subs or Functions inside Subs or Functions

Comment: I know, but that's what's weird. I modified somewhat the code you wrote to fit my actual file, but after the end sub and typing the new sub, it marks the new sub as the error, even though it is after the end sub from the first one.

Comment: Then I'd recommend that you start over with a new module and copy your code, method by method.